# How to get a duration that exclude defined weekdays from a duration table SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a duration between two dates except weekend for each month ( if the duration combine two months, I  have a two table ( one to get the duration and the other to get the work days )

My object is:

- Split the duration to each month , for example :

****I Suppose that Friday is weekend.****

```
 DayId      DayName

  1         Sunday
  2         Monday 
  3         Tuesday
  4         Wednesday
  5         Thursday
  7         Saturday
```

Duration table:

```
  StartDate            Endate          Duration

  2021-03-17         2021-03-25           8
  2021-03-28         2021-04-02           5
```

Expected Results:

```
  StartDate            Endate          Duration

  2021-03-17         2021-03-25           8
  2021-03-28         2021-03-31           4
  2021-04-01         2021-04-02           1
```

The duration calculated ( take into account the day of `start_date` and the day of `end_date` except the day off=> Friday
`Get_CalendarDate` SQL function:

```
USE [Attendance]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[Get_Calendar_Date]    Script Date: 3/18/2021 12:26:36 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_Calendar_Date]
(
    @StartDate DATETIME
,   @EndDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
 
RETURN
(
    SELECT  Tbl_Obj.RNo
        ,   DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate) AS [Date]
        ,   DATEPART(quarter,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Quarter]
        ,   DATEPART(dayofyear,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [DayofYear]
        ,   DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [WeekofYear]
        ,   DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Year]
        ,   DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Month]
        ,   DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Day]
        ,   DATEPART(weekday,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Weekday]
        ,   DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [MonthName]
        ,   DATENAME(weekday,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [WeekdayName]
        ,   (RIGHT( REPLICATE('0',(4)) +
                CONVERT([VARCHAR],DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)),0)
                ,(4)
             )+
             RIGHT( REPLICATE('0',(2)) +
                CONVERT([VARCHAR],DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)),0)
                ,(2)
             )
            ) AS [Vintage]
 
    FROM    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) AS [RNo]
              FROM sys.all_objects WITH (NOLOCK)
            ) Tbl_Obj
          
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate) <= @EndDate
)
```

How to get a duration that exclude defined weekend from a duration table SQL Server?

Comment: Sounds like a Calendar Table might be useful here. Also, *why* are you using `NOLOCK` against `sys.all_objects` of all places..?

Comment: Sorry my question was not cleared , I'm so confused about the problem , I've update my question .

Comment: I stand by my statement of *"Sounds like a Calendar Table might be useful here."* and that doesn't answer *why* are you using `NOLOCK` against `sys.all_objects`. Also, how do you get a duration of `1` for `2021-04-01` to `2021-03-02`? How does something end 30 days before it starts?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake , I've update my answer I mean `2021-04-01` to `2021-04-02`

Comment: You know you need a calendar table. Trivially searching will find hundreds of examples and thousands of discussion regarding population of one and the logic needed for "work days" vs "non-work days". That searching will also encounter discussions about holidays and other non-work days (like disasters). Believe me - you WILL need to do this (or perhaps someone else that needs to fix your code).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest expanding out the days using a recursive CTE and then filtering:

```
with cte as (
      select id, startdate, enddate
      from duration
      union all
      select id, dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate
      from cte
      where startdate < enddate
     )
select min(startdate), max(startdate),
       sum(case when datepart(weekday, startdate) not in (1, 7) then 1 else 0 end) as duration
from cte
group by id, year(startdate), month(startdate);
```

This assumes that each row has an `id` to make this simpler for combining all the results from one row..

Note that this uses the built-in functions for the day of the week.  I don't see any use for your table, because it still relies on getting the date of week from `datepart()`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=654d4dc95389b9a46c4bb1a84455ca00) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: But I need to use the table days for some reason because it have relation with other tables.

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 . . . You can join to it instead of using the `case` expression. There is just no utility because SQL Server has a function that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Using the other solution that you have provided , I think that I have fixed my solution

Comment: I said in te other question that I need a custom dayoff not `1,7` , please see again the other question ( I have table called working_days)